# Why IsEmpty() works with cell

Tags: excel, vba

This probably a silly question, but I've been unable to track down an answer.  According to  MS help:

> IsEmpty only returns meaningful information for variants.

However, I see many examples (by pros) of it being used to check cell contents `If IsEmpty(Cells(1,1) Then do something`, so consequently I've learned to use it that way too.  So I know it works.  But if I went by what MS help said, I wouldn't think it was OK to use it this way.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Juhana, Just wondering why you edited my post (just so I get it right the next time).  Thanks.

Comment: You used code formatting for something that isn't code. When you quote something use quote formatting.

Comment: Thanks, I'll remember that for next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the Range.Value property [returns a Variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) itself I'm thinking it's not too much of a stretch to see why that should work.

Comment: Doh!!  This is something I should have known, but somehow missed.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When using a reference like `IsEmpty(Cells(1,1))` you are refering to the default property of `Cells(1,1)` which is `.Value`.  The data type of `.Value` is `Variant`, so its consistent with the docs!

Comment: I was adding extra info on a comparison between `IsEmpty()` and `Len(Trim())` :P

Comment: But, but... Siddharth, *I* won by 25 seconds! With a link and everything! 8^>

Comment: Thank you, you're a very kind guru. (And I must admit to having been surprised as Chris to have gotten to this one before you.)

Comment: @chrisneilsen: Do you think a added explanation on `IsEmpty()` and `Len(Trim())` might clear OP's doubts?

Comment: I think the OP's focus is on the Data Type, rather than testing for the various manifestations of an "empty" cell. And there are lots of other Q's on testing for empty.

Comment: Thanks for your answer(s) - as I can only check 1 answer, I'll go with Alan K because he was first, but both answers are good.